# Custom inventory items based on inheritance

Tags: c#, unity, rpg, inheritance

So, here's the scenario:
I'm building an RPG. Like most of the other RPGs on the market, my game will feature an inventory and of course, inventory items. So far I've worked well with using a single class for all items, because I did not need anything else than character stat alteration on item usage (consumption). However, I'd like some items to have a more exotic effect. Think of something like when the user consumes a transformation potion, he automatically turns into a beast.

In order to achieve this I've thought about declaring a new class that inherits from BaseItem for each item. Each descendant would override some methods (like void OnConsume()), to change the base behavior.

This works fine, but when it comes to inventory management, I have some issues. The actual inventory will have to work with BaseItem components only (for obvious reasons, as it's an enumerable collection of objects of the same type); casting any descendant to the base class is possible, so no problems in adding items to the inventory. But how can I keep track of the descendant's type (class) for each item in the inventory? And how to perform the descendant's OnConsume from withint he inventory, for each item?

Let me know if you can think of a better solution than mine, or if you can think of a solution to my problem only.

Development is done in C#, inside Unity 3.5.

Thanks!

Comment: Gotta edit: apparently, casting back to the descendant isn't actually possible. So the problem is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Well inheritance should take care of basically all your problems. The game will be sure to call the proper "OnConsume" method of the child class so you don't really need to worry about it. If you want to cast the object to a subclass use something like "BeastPotion potion = item as BeastPotion; if (potion != null) { ... }"

Comment: Funny thing though: I have decided to not use inheritance at all. It's possible that I might have gotten around 900 custom classes in the end. I'm now using only the BaseItem class, paired with delegates to custom methods for item behavior. So basically, each item is a BaseItem instance, with an OnPickup/OnConsume field that uses the appropriate delegate to link the item to its custom behavior.

Comment: So it goes like this: BaseItem it = new BaseItem() ... it.OnConsume = TheAppropriateMethodForThisItem; I'm quite happy with the result, and it's a lot cleaner, in my opinion, than my first idea w/ inheritance usage.

Comment: ah, honestly I can't say I would recommend that, but it's not wrong. I personally just find things easier to use inheritance in the event I need to backtrack for mistakes (since I can just open the class with the item name rather than look for where I stored all my delegate methods.) Either way works and so long as you are consistent and have a way to easily find the code you need to work on. I just like subclassing because it extracts the shared code (like removing the item after it is used) and you only have write code for the effects.

Comment: It's fine so far, regarding usability; items use 3 callbacks only, for three events: on pickup, on consume and on drop. All methods are organized, so that I may get to the right one by searching the file for the item's ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To [check whether an object is an instance of a class in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561320), use the `is` keyword:

```
var item = inventory.getItem( ... );

if ( item is SpecialItem ) {
    var specialItem = (SpecialItem) item;
    // do something special...
}
```

or just cast it with `as` and see if it succeeds:

```
var specialItem = item as SpecialItem;
if ( specialItem != null ) {
    // do something special...
}
```

See also: [How to: Safely Cast by Using as and is Operators (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488006.aspx)

---

**Edit:** To keep track of your items, you should organize them into a reasonable class hierarchy instead of having all of them inherit directly from `BaseItem`.  So, for example, a helmet might be an instance of class `Helmet`, which extends `Headgear`, which extends `Armor`, which extends `Wearable` (armor, jewelry, etc.) which extends `BaseItem`.  (Of course, you don't *have* to do it exactly like this.  For example, if you have no use for a separate class for headgear, you can just have `Helmet` inherit directly from `Armor`.)

You'll probably also want to use [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173156.aspx) to describe different aspects an item might have.  For example, imagine that you want to have a magic helmet.  Obviously, you could have a parent class `MagicItem` for all magic items, but C# won't let you inherit from both `Helmet` and `MagicItem` at the same time.  Instead, you can define an interface `IMagicItem` that any item class can implement to indicate that it's magic (and provide methods to invoke its magic effects), and declare your magic helmet class like this:

```
public class MagicHelmet: Helmet, IMagicItem {
    // Implement the IMagicItem interface here, and optionally override some
    // methods from Helmet.
}
```

You could also, for example, define an `IWearable` interface in addition to (or instead of) the `Wearable` class, so that when you decide to, say, implement a flower that can be worn on the head (or maybe a tame parrot that can be worn on the shoulder), you can do that even though neither `Flower` nor `Parrot` are subclasses of `Wearable`.

(Ps. I had to go AFK for a while as I was writing this edit, and I see from the comments that you managed to solve your real problem in the meanwhile.  I'll post this anyway, since it might still be helpful.)

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea about the "as" and "is" operators. This simplifies the problem by a lot! How would you suggest to keep track of the derived class of each item in the inventory? Suppose you have a simple list like List<BaseItem>. Each entry in the list can be any of... 10 derived classes, cast back to BaseItem.

Comment: Further details: since there will be more than 100 items, there will be more than 100 separate classes (descendants of BaseItem). Trying to see if a BaseItem is actually one of the descendants by going through each one of the descendants and using "is" or "as" would be horribly slow.

Comment: Sorry for sounding so dumb :) I have refreshed my knowledge of inheritance. Apparently, overriding a virtual method in a descendant, casting back to the base class, and calling the virtual method again actually calls the descendant's overridden method. So basically any BaseItem.OnConsume() will actually call the descendant's OnConsume(). Problem solved, and I'll accept your answer as correct. Thanks!